# New props not being passed to axios.interceptor when testing with jest and enzyme

Tags: reactjs, react-router, axios, enzyme, jestjs

Im having issues testing to see if my axios.intercepters will push to the login page on 401. My code is hitting the interceptors but wont get through my if statement due to the `this.props.location.pathname` not being updated even though Im `wrapper.setProps({ location: { pathname: '/dashboard' } })`

**Relevant Code from AppContainer**

```
componentWillMount = async () => {
  axios.interceptors.response.use(
    response => response,
    error => (
      error.response.status === 401 && this.props.location.pathname !== '/'
        ? this.props.history.push('/account/login')
        : error
    ),
  );

  const { data } = await Account.auth();
  this.setState({ isAuth: data.isAuth });
}
```

**Relevant code from my test**

```
describe('AppContainer', () => {
let wrapper = null;
let instance = null;

const mockProps = {
  history: { push: jest.fn(), replace: jest.fn() },
  location: { pathname: '/' },
};

beforeEach(() => {
  mock.reset();
  mock.onGet('/api/account/auth').reply(200, { isAuth: true });
  wrapper = shallow(<AppContainer {...mockProps} />);
  instance = wrapper.instance();
});

it('should redirect to /account/login if api calls error 401 and location is not "/"', async () => {
  mock.onGet('/mockCall').reply(401);
  wrapper.setProps({ location: { pathname: '/dashboard' } });
  instance.mockCall = () => axios.get('/mockCall');

  await instance.mockCall();
  expect(instance.props.history.push).toHaveBeenLastCalledWith('/account/login');
});
```

Logging inside of componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) shows that `this.props.location.pathname = '/dashboard'` but logging inside of my error function on the axios.interceptor shows the previous props and not the new props coming in.
My expect `toHaveBeenLastCalledWith('/account/login')` is showing that it hasnt been called at all

Is my interceptor in the wrong spot?